# unittest error when importing from different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-unittest

I've been trying to use unittest in my latest project but I have some difficulties with the imports.

I've managed to import the script I want to test successfully but this script fails when it comes to its own imports.

My folder is structured as:

```
Project
 |
 +-- src
 |   |
 |   +-- __init__.py
 |   +-- script1.py
 |   +-- script2.py
 |
 +-- test
  |  |
  |  +-- __init__.py
  |  +-- test_script1.py
```

---

The `script1.py` contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""
    This is the script I want to run tests on
"""
import networkx as nx  # works just fine
from script2 import blablabla  # does not work when called from unittest
```

and this is what my `test_script1.py` look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import unittest
import networkx as nx
import src.script1
```

When I'm trying to run the tests using this command `~/Project$ python -m unittest discover` I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script2'`.

If I change in `script1.py` to `from .script2 import blablabla` then unittests runs just fine but `script1.py` alone (not using unittest) is not anymore since it can not find `script2`.

Any idea how I can solve this ?

Comment: Can you try making your import in `script1.py` `from src.script2 import blah`?

Comment: I did, it works for unittest but running `python src/script1.py` or `cd src; python script1.py` fails in this case

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to keep your imports and packages as they are, but just set the `PYTHONPATH` before running the test.

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:src python -m unittest discover
```